# Getting json data from PHP into my JavaScript to flot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, flot

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this.

I have a php script which returns the following:

```
[{"label":"0","data":"261"},{"label":"1653","data":"1"},{"label":"1654","data":"6"},{"label":"1655","data":"2"},{"label":"1656","data":"10"},{"label":"1657","data":"5"},{"label":"1658","data":"4"},{"label":"1659","data":"10"},{"label":"1660","data":"5"},{"label":"1661","data":"3"}]
```

I want to call this php script from my javascript (which is then called from my html file) to plot a chart using flot.

The php script seems to work as planned to create the above output.

But I can't seem to assign the above data to a variable correctly in my JavaScript. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I want to assign the output of the php to a variable called tan and then use that as the source of the flot pie-chart.

```
var tan = Null
$.ajax({
  url:"http://myurl/chartdata2.php",
  type:"POST",
  dataType: "json",
  async:false,
 // data:{accountid:Account},
  success:function(d){
    tan = d;
  }
});
```

And then calling my flot function:

```
  $("#flot-pie-donut").length && $.plot($("#flot-pie-donut"), tan, {
    series: {
      pie: {
        innerRadius: 0.4,
        show: true,
        stroke: {
          width: 0
        },
        label: {
          show: true,
          threshold: 0.05
        },

      }
    },
    colors: ["#65b5c2","#4da7c1","#3993bb","#2e7bad","#23649e"],
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: false
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      content: "%s: %p.0%"
    }
  });
```

Thank you!

Comment: How / when are you calling your `flot` function? If you don't do that from the ajax success function you could be calling it too soon / when the ajax call has not yet finished.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have successfully get the data from ajax call. So I would guess this is your `data formatting problem` before it was passed into `flot`

try this:

```
var tan = Null
$.ajax({
  url:"http://myurl/chartdata2.php",
  type:"POST",
  dataType: "json",
  async:false,
 // data:{accountid:Account},
  success:function(d){
    tan = d;
    process(tan);
  }
});

var _tan = [];
function process(tan){

    for (var i = 0; i < tan.length; i++){

          // format the data array into [label,data]
          _tan.push([tan[i].label,tan[i].data]);
    }
}
```

Then in your jflot:

```
$("#flot-pie-donut").length && $.plot($("#flot-pie-donut"), _tan, {
series: {
  pie: {
    innerRadius: 0.4,
    show: true,
    stroke: {
      width: 0
    },
    label: {
      show: true,
      threshold: 0.05
    },

  }
},
colors: ["#65b5c2","#4da7c1","#3993bb","#2e7bad","#23649e"],
grid: {
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: false
},
tooltip: true,
tooltipOpts: {
  content: "%s: %p.0%"
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1) You need to call the `plot` method after you fetched your data in the `success` callback of the `ajax` method. Now you  start plotting the chart before the data comes back from the `AJAX` call.

2) Your data is not correctly formatted. `flot` needs one array of  "data series" arrays of "data points" arrays. And it should be numbers instead of string. Going from your example data

```
[{"label":"0","data":"261"},{"label":"1653","data":"1"}, ...]
```

change it to

```
[ [ [0, 261], [1653, 1], ... ] ] .
```

You can do this in your `php` code or with `javascript`. If you want to do it with `javascript` your `success` callback method should then look like this:

```
success: function(d) {
    tan = [[]];
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        tan[0].push(parseInt(d[i].label), parseInt(d[i].data));
    }
    $("#flot-pie-donut").length && $.plot($("#flot-pie-donut"), tan, {
       // your original code for the plot method
    });
}
```